React Native to be run in the background
I have a react native app that i need to run in the background , this app needs to do the following

Listen to notifications that comes as events
this should also happen when the app is running in the background
is there a way to know if my app is running and capturing events in the background

currently i have faced a issue even when the app is open and left inactive the app goes to sleep mode and is not able to listen to notifications.
I have used something called BackgroundService and the implementation is something like this
onst fetchNewNotifications = async i => {
  console.log('run task here');

  await BackgroundService.updateNotification({
    taskDesc: 'Checking for new notifications ' + i,
  });
};

const headlessNotificationListener = async ({notification}) => {
  console.log('notification------>', notification);
};

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask(
      RNAndroidNotificationListenerHeadlessJsName,
      () => headlessNotificationListener,
    );

    const startBackgroundService = async () => {
      await BackgroundService.start(task, options);
      // Uncomment if you need to update notification details
      // await BackgroundService.updateNotification({
      //   taskDesc: 'Checking for new notifications',
      // });
    };

    startBackgroundService();

    // Cleanup is not necessary since we don't want to stop the background task
    // return () => {
    //   BackgroundService.stop();
    // };
  }, []);


